# I can not send controller map to function which is return a widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try create `TextEditingController` and send to this controller to my function and I want to use at button`onPressed` method. When I click button and printed function variable it came empty map. How can I send controllers to other functions ?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'funcs.dart';

class EmailRegister extends StatefulWidget {
  EmailRegister() : super();

  @override
  _EmailRegisterState createState() => _EmailRegisterState();
}

class _EmailRegisterState extends State<EmailRegister> {
  TextEditingController _email;
  TextEditingController _pass;
  TextEditingController _name;
  var Controllers = new Map();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = new TextEditingController();
    _pass = new TextEditingController();
    _name = new TextEditingController();
    Controllers['email'] = _email;
    Controllers['name'] = _name;
    Controllers['pass'] = _pass;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _email.dispose();
    _pass.dispose();
    _name.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            CreateFormLabel("Email", 20, 20, false, _email),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CreateFormLabel("UserName", 20, 20, false, _name),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CreateFormLabel("Password", 20, 20, true, _pass),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CreateFormButton(
                "register",
                18,
                40.0,
                10.0,
                40.0,
                10.0,
                Colors.blue,
                Colors.white,
                Colors.white, Controllers),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and CreateFormButton code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget CreateFormLabel(
    String text, double edgeInsetL, double edgeInsetR, bool obscureText, controller) {
  return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: edgeInsetR, left: edgeInsetL),
    child: TextField(
      obscureText: obscureText,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: text,
      ),
      controller: controller,
    ),
  );
}

Widget CreateFormButton(String text, double FontSize, double L, double T,
    double R, double B, color, textClor, splashColor, controllers) {
  return Center(
    child: FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print(controllers);

      },
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: FontSize),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(L, T, R, B),
      color: color,
      textColor: textClor,
      splashColor: splashColor,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map<String, TextEditingController> Controllers = new Map();`

code snippet

```
Widget CreateFormButton(
      String text,
      double FontSize,
      double L,
      double T,
      double R,
      double B,
      color,
      textClor,
      splashColor,
      Map<String, TextEditingController> controllers) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(Controllers['email'].text);
          print(Controllers['name'].text);
          print(Controllers['pass'].text);
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: EmailRegister(),
    );
  }
}


class EmailRegister extends StatefulWidget {
  EmailRegister() : super();

  @override
  _EmailRegisterState createState() => _EmailRegisterState();
}

class _EmailRegisterState extends State<EmailRegister> {
  TextEditingController _email;
  TextEditingController _pass;
  TextEditingController _name;
  Map<String, TextEditingController> Controllers = new Map();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = new TextEditingController();
    _pass = new TextEditingController();
    _name = new TextEditingController();
    Controllers['email'] = _email;
    Controllers['name'] = _name;
    Controllers['pass'] = _pass;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _pass.dispose();
    _name.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            CreateFormLabel("Email", 20, 20, false, _email),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CreateFormLabel("UserName", 20, 20, false, _name),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CreateFormLabel("Password", 20, 20, true, _pass),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            CreateFormButton("register", 18, 40.0, 10.0, 40.0, 10.0,
                Colors.blue, Colors.white, Colors.white, Controllers),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget CreateFormLabel(String text, double edgeInsetL, double edgeInsetR,
      bool obscureText, controller) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: edgeInsetR, left: edgeInsetL),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: obscureText,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: text,
        ),
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget CreateFormButton(
      String text,
      double FontSize,
      double L,
      double T,
      double R,
      double B,
      color,
      textClor,
      splashColor,
      Map<String, TextEditingController> controllers) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          print(Controllers['email'].text);
          print(Controllers['name'].text);
          print(Controllers['pass'].text);
        },
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: FontSize),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(L, T, R, B),
        color: color,
        textColor: textClor,
        splashColor: splashColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]